# How do you compute the slope for weighted least squares?

Tags: regression, linear-model, linear

You can compute the slope of linear regression (without weights) by:

cor(x, y) * sd(y) / sd(x)

If we have add weights (w) in here as well - how do you compute the slope then?

Comment: Basically, you in general form you can use ordinary least squares, and with weights, you can use the [weighted form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_least_squares), is this what you ask, or is it if you can use correlations and variances for this?

Comment: The duplicate threads were discovered by inspecting the highest-voted relevant hits in the search https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=weighted%20%22least%20squares%22.  Other hits may be of interest, too.